# Ethereum Keystore Hashcat

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereum-classic, hash, dao

I have a keystore file but I can't remember all the passwords.

Then I use Hashcat and I try to crack it with my list of words that I made but I don't know if I use the correct commands.

```
hashcat.exe -a0 -m 15700 --force -D1 hashcode.txt password.txt -w3
```

I just want to compare my password file with the hash.

Thanks in advance